# Is there any disadvantage of assigning numbers as keys to Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Recently I've been working on a News App where I store information of news artciles in Firebase database. Following is an image of the structure of my Firebase database.

[image: Firebase database structure]

I read somewhere that it is not advisable to keep numbers as keys for Firebase database. However, I've not been able to figure out any explanation for this. Is there any norm that Firebase keys should not be numbers ?

If so, can I have key names as National_01, National_02, National_03... and so on for each news category?

Comment: I guess its ok to assign keys like that.

Comment: don't spam with irrelevant tags. your question is not related to android studio at all.

Comment: See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** It is okay to use keys like "National_01" for static data and mini projects; Use Push Keys for dynamic data and big projects.

Here are some benefits of using Firebase Push Keys

**Push Keys are automatically generated**

If you continue to use manually created keys whenever you will have to update the data you have to do create a key like this:

`String category = "National;"
count = count + 1;
String key = category + count.toString();
// Not say keep track of the "count" too`

Instead, if you decide to use Firebase Auto-Generated Push Keys:

`String key = mDatabase.child(category).push().getKey();`

**Nearly Impossible to Duplicate Push Keys**

If you use self-generated keys there might me an error in creating keys hence creating a duplicate key. In that case, you might loose data since you overwrite data under the original key you duplicated.

Whereas, push ids are nearly impossible to duplicate and take no extra code to implement.

**The Conclusion**

So continue to use self-generated keys only and only if your data is static (which I don't think it should be coz it's a news app) and you don't wish to scale this static data (which again is unrealistic to imagine for a news app).

But remember it is PROGAMATICALLY EASY to work with Push Keys and is FUTURE PROOF in case you intend to Scale your app in future. :)

**Edit**

Moreover, the Push Keys generated are generated based on `timestamp` hence all the keys will be sorted chronologically by default!!

Answer (score 1):

Using key names in your Firebase database is not a bad practice but according to your app complexity you can choose whenever to use those keys or the random generated keys.

Using the keys generated by the `push()` method, guarantees you the uniqueness, because the algorithm is based on a `timestamp`. Because of this, all your items will automatically be ordered chronologically.

If you want the users to post news in your app, because Firebase generates a unique key for each new news, no write conflicts will occur if multiple users add a post at the same time. This cannot be achieved with your `key names` in a very simple way.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the record: I've read in the Firebase Best Practices documentation, that you shouldn't use custom keys for large projects, because that will disable the sharding method used in the background.

You can check further details at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices